# Json Parse Issue

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

I have very simple -sample class for the following json which I kept in custom label for simplicity.

Sample JSON Which I have kept in Custom Label for simplicity : Label Name : Smple_Resp

```
{
    "Details": {
        "Status": "SUCCESS"
    }
}
```

Class to parse the Json.

```
public class TestUtil{
public class Details{
    String Status;
}

public static Details parseDetails(String json) {
    return (Details) System.JSON.deserialize(json, Details.class);
}
}
```

Code which I ran in Workbench

```
    String testing =label.Smple_Resp;
system.debug(TestUtil.parseDetails(testing));
```

Debug which I am getting

```
05:56:27.25 (30728351)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Details:[Status=null]
```

Unable to understand what mistake I have done which is returning me NULL value all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of a very common mistake with JSON deserialization: you have an extra layer of structure in your JSON that's not represented in your Apex.

To successfully deserialize, you need an outer structure to correspond to the `"Details"` key. I would do it like this:

```
public class DetailsStruct {
    String Status;
}

public class JSONResponse {
     DetailsStruct Details;
}
```

The object into which you're deserializing has to match the outermost object layer in your JSON.